# Generating a report from bash output

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am currently trying to write a script in Bash that can run a set of unit/integration tests. I have that part working, but what I need now is to be able to output a summary at the end. I have been trying to use `grep` ot grab every line which contains a number followed by the string `failing`, save it in a variable, and print it at the end.

So an example of a failing output is

```
224 passing (3m)
47 failing
```

What I would like to be printed at the end is something along the lines of

```
service01 4 failing
service03 1 failing
```

What I have so far is:

```
OUTPUT=""
for service in ${array[*]}
do
  echo $service
  if [ $DO_API == 'true' ]
  then
    echo 'running API tests'
    OUTPUT+="$service API $(docker exec -it $service npm run api_test | tee /dev/tty | grep -e '[0-9]+ failing' )"
  fi

  if [ $DO_CI == 'true' ]
  then
    echo 'running CI tests'
    OUTPUT+="$service CI $(docker exec -it $service npm run ci | tee /dev/tty | grep -e '[0-9]+ failing' )"
  fi
  echo $'\n'
done
```

The above script shows no output when there are failing tests, which leads me to believe it is my grep syntax at fault.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your grep will only find 0..9 failures. You will need to expand that if you expect 10 or more failures! Like this: `grep -e '[0-9]+ failed'`

Comment: Welcome to the U&L SE. I am not sure if this is a typo - the sample output shows 'failing' and you're grepping for 'failed'. These two patterns will never match.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've updated the script with your respective suggestions (as well as also piping to the console), but I still only get the service name, and not the number of failing tests.

Comment: @JavaTheNutt Can you try `grep -E '[0-9]+ failing'` (note the capital E) instead? I believe the '+' quantifier requires extended regex to be enabled.

Comment: @Haxiel That works! Thank you! If you want to make an answer I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `grep` command will return the required output:

```
grep -E '[0-9]+ failing'
```

The pattern `[0-9]+` matches one or more digits. The `-E` option must be used so that `grep` can interpret the pattern as an extended regular expression. The `+` quantifier is not defined as part of the basic regular expressions.

Sample run (using a file):

```
$ cat testfile
224 passing (3m)
47 failing

$ grep -E '[0-9]+ failing' testfile
47 failing
```

As an aside, this pattern can also be implemented using basic regular expressions (BRE) in the following manner:

```
$ grep '[0-9]\{1,\} failing' testfile
47 failing
```

In this case, the `{n,m}` quantifier is used to match one or more digits. The backslashes are required to give the curly braces their special meaning.